# I had an error in my html project and renaming the file fixes it or makes it reoccur

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to get into web development and got started on a simple website with a top bar for three different tabs that you can click through. That top bar started to resize when changing tabs and then reloading the website and I didn't know why.

I commented out everything, literally every bit of html that wasn't the "a" components for the tabs or a container thereof and all of my css and javascript and it still resized. I then made a new file where I just had those parts and deleted the comments and it worked. I then tried to rename my original file and nothing weird happened either. Now, when I rename it back to "main.html" it breaks again, when it's called anything else it works. Here's the full code before I commented anything out:

```js
// script.js

function showHome() {
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("timeline").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";

  document.querySelector('a[href="#home"]').classList.add('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#timeline"]').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#about"]').classList.remove('active');

  const homeTab = document.querySelector('a[href="#home"]');
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  line.style.left = `${homeTab.offsetLeft + homeTab.offsetWidth / 2 - line.offsetWidth / 2}px`;
}

function showTimeline() {
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("timeline").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";

  document.querySelector('a[href="#home"]').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#timeline"]').classList.add('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#about"]').classList.remove('active');


  const timelineTab = document.querySelector('a[href="#timeline"]');
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  line.style.left = `${timelineTab.offsetLeft + timelineTab.offsetWidth / 2 - line.offsetWidth / 2}px`;
}

function showAbout() {
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("timeline").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";

  document.querySelector('a[href="#home"]').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#timeline"]').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('a[href="#about"]').classList.add('active');


  const aboutTab = document.querySelector('a[href="#about"]');
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  line.style.left = `${aboutTab.offsetLeft + aboutTab.offsetWidth / 2 - line.offsetWidth / 2}px`;
}

function updateTabInfo() {
  var hashtag = window.location.hash;

  for (let tab of ['home', 'timeline', 'about']) {
    if (hashtag == `#${tab}`) {
      document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
      document.querySelector(`a[href="#${tab}"]`).classList.add('active');
    } else {
      document.getElementById(`${tab}`).style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector(`[href="#${tab}"]`).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  const currentTab = document.querySelector(`a[href="${hashtag}"]`);
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  line.style.left = `${currentTab.offsetLeft + currentTab.offsetWidth / 2 - line.offsetWidth / 2}px`;
}

window.onload = function() {
  updateTabInfo()
};
```

```css
/* style.css */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Regular';
  src: url('fonts/palanquindark-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Medium';
  src: url('fonts/palanquindark-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Semibold';
  src: url('fonts/palanquindark-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Bold';
  src: url('fonts/palanquindark-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

#top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 7%;
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Bold', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Regular', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#content h1 {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Palanquin Dark Semibold', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.timeline-element {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#timeline {
  margin: auto 0;
}

#timeline-elements {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.tab-container {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  background-color: black;
  height: 4px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- main.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <div id="top-bar">
    <nav>
      <a href="#home" onclick="showHome()">Home</a>
      <a href="#timeline" onclick="showTimeline()">Timeline</a>
      <a href="#about" onclick="showAbout()">About</a>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="home">
      <h1>Welcome to my beautiful website</h1>
      <p>well not quite beautiful yet but believe me we're getting there chat gpt is helping me with the technical stuff and i'm doing all of the design decisions</p>
    </div>
    <div id="timeline" style="display: none">
      <div id="timeline-elements">
        <div id="timeline-moon-landing" class="timeline-element">
          <img src="images/timeline/moon-landing.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="timeline-deep-blue" class="timeline-element">
          <img src="images/timeline/deep-blue.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div id="timeline-iphone" class="timeline-element">
          <img src="images/timeline/iphone.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about" style="display: none">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

To test and debug the file I just dragged and dropped it into chrome.

Please focus on the specific question although I am sure I could use a lot of input on general html/css/javascript structure as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue or attach a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Top bar elements had some arbitrary size depending on the active tab that got applied only when I reloaded the page or focused another one in Chrome and then went back. Renaming the file fixed it, reducing it to only the html elements for the tabs, no CSS and no JS didn't. Seems like Chrome had some info saved about the file somewhere from some earlier working version that changed its behaviour.

Comment: Good to know! Glad its working for you. Consider posting what you just said above as an answer to your own question to help others in the future. Also, a hard refresh to your browser would have been a potential solution to your problem as well: `Chrome, Firefox, or Edge for Windows: Press Ctrl+F5 (If that doesn't work, try Shift+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R). Chrome or Firefox for Mac: Press Shift+Command+R. Safari for Mac: There is no simple keyboard shortcut to force a hard refresh.`